# What is best method to link PDF(with icon)?

Tags: css, xhtml, usability, accessibility, screen-readers

What is preferred method to link PDF(with icon) on a page in terms of semantic, accessibility, usability and SEO?

for example

- this is a name of PDF "01ccc5.pdf"
  but inside PDF this is the title of
  PDF "How to search in long PDF"
  Should i use PDF subject as a file
  name like "How-to-search-in-long-PDF?
- and I want to show link of PDF as a
  PDF icon on the page, What is the
  best way in terms of accessibility
  and usability.
- Should i insert pdf icon as a 
  inside  or i should use as a css
  background?

---

Which method is better? this

```
a{text-indent:-99999px}

<a href="How-to-search-in-long-pdf.pdf" title="PDF, 25KB, Opens in a new window">
How to search in long PDF 
<img src=pdf-icon.jpg" alt="How to search in long PDF" />
</a>
```

---

or this

```
  a{text-indent:-99999px;background:url(pdf-icon.jpg);width:32px:height:32px}
```

or this method http://www.askthecssguy.com/2006/12/showing_hyperlink_cues_with_cs_1.html

```
<a href="How-to-search-in-long-pdf.pdf" title="PDF, 25KB, Opens in a new window">
How to search in long PDF </a>
```

I have to link multiple PDF

---

Note:

Title of PDF is also will be available before PDF but without any link

like this:

```
Title                                      PDF

How to search in long PDF                  PDF icon (with link of PDF)

How to search in long PDF                  PDF icon (with link of PDF)

How to search in long PDF                  PDF icon (with link of PDF)
```

Answer (score 2):

### Easy way to bring pdf or other icon with each link using CSS3:

**1. icon through background image ->** CSS Code:

```
a[href$=".pdf"]
{
  background:url("your-pdf-image.png") no-repeat left;
  padding-left:25px;
}
```

**2. bring icon from FontAwesome ->** CSS Code:

```
a[href$=".pdf"]:before
{
  content:"\f1c1  ";
  font-family: fontawesome;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The last one is the best since everything is in the CSS. However, it doesn't work in IE6- and as much as we would all like this browser to die, it is still well used.

So, I'd use the second one, with a special class (e.g. `a.pdf`). And if you have multiple links with different file types, use [sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/).

Edit: I've just understood why you used a negative text-indent. I'm not sure it will work properly with a background. In that case, I'd probably use an `img` with an `alt` text and no text content for the `a`. I nearly always favor using a text and an image, especially for download links.

Comment: although for IE6 we can use javascript to get work that selector